# How to write to a file saved in project directory

Tags: android, file, android-multidex

I'm trying to write to a file at run time saved in project directory. But I'm getting below error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: multidex.keep: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

I'm I giving a wrong file path or I cannot edit the files at runtime? Please suggest. Below is my code:

```
private void saveInMultidexKeepFile(List externalDexClasses) {
        if (externalDexClasses != null && externalDexClasses.size() > 0) {
            File file = new File("multidex.keep");
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                OutputStreamWriter outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                for (int i = 0; i < externalDexClasses.size(); i++) {
                    outWriter.append(externalDexClasses.get(i).toString());
                    outWriter.append("\n");
                    LOGD("Multidex:", outWriter.toString());
                }
                outWriter.close();
                fOut.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LOGD("Multidex:", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LOGD("Multidex:", e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `in project directory` What do you consider to be the project directory? Please give full path.

Comment: Try `fOut = openFileOutput(filename );` Or use full path: `File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "multidex.keep");`.

Comment: @greenapps, project directory is the one under which build, src, libs, build.gradle files are present. I have created a file under this folder and want to edit it at run time

Comment: But that is on your PC. In directories of Android Studio workspace. Your app on your Android device has no access to them! What do you have in mind?

Comment: Our app launch is delayed after using multidex. In this article ,"medium.com/groupon-eng/… " - it was suggested to add all loaded external classes in multidex.keep file. Adding this improves performance. So, i was trying this solution. but getting this error. There is no way to edit this file?

Comment: It;s not possible?

Comment: Please first react to what i said.

Comment: I already answered your question. It was suggested in the article to write to that file at run time, to reduce cold start delay. So, was trying that solution

Comment: No. I told you that an app on an Android device has no access to your PC. You ignored that.

Comment: But all those code will be a part of the apk right? And I'm not trying access the folder saved in my system. I'm trying edit the fiel saved in my project directory

Comment: Your app has no project directory. The file you mention is used by Android Studio. Why would you think it's packed in the apk? `What do you consider to be the project directory? Please give full path. ` If files in assets directory are packed in the apk yes then your app has access to them.

Comment: path of the file is app/multidex.keep. This folder containes src, lbs etc. And I tried putting file in assets. Even in that case also, it's giving same error: multidex.keep: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: Yes of course that will give the same error if the file is in assets. Why would you think it would look in assets? It does not. It searches the file system. Please google for reading file from assets.

Comment: I read..Most of them suggested that at run time whatever stored in assets is read -only.We cannot edit it at run time

Comment: All in assets is read only. You copy the 'file' first to the file system. Then you edit that file.

Comment: file system- This will be stored in the internal/external storage right?

Comment: But why would you transfer that file to an Android device and edit it there? What would that bring? If that file is used by Android Studio then edit the file on your PC.

Comment: Internal or external. Just what you want. You decide.

Comment: But this is of no use for me. As per that article I must run it once, write all loaded classes in to this file. So,when his is installed in other devices, if classes are present in this file, it will not load those classes again, thus reducing app launch time. But in the sample given in that article is completly opposite to what he said. So, I just wanted to give a try, if it can reduce the delay

Comment: Launch time? Compile, link, install and launch? That has to do with Android Studio. You should edit the file on your PC. Reread the article.

Comment: But editing the file manually is not a good choice right..When a new lib is added, again that must be added to that file. And I tried editing the file from PC too...But delay is not reduced

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply cannot, why you want modify this file?

Comment: Our app launch is delayed after using multidex. In this article ,"https://medium.com/groupon-eng/android-s-multidex-slows-down-app-startup-d9f10b46770f#.j01kgi48u "  - it was suggested to add all loaded external classes in multidex.keep file. Adding this improves performance.  So, i was trying this solution. but getting this error. There is no way to edit this file?